# Error on Video Indexing process with .mp4 videos

Tags: azure-video-indexer

I'm trying without any success to index a .mp4 video. I get an error arount the 70% of the indexing process.
I've received an email saying that the file format it's not supported and it seems strange to me.

This is the ID:
Trial---7a3be47a47---e9dfcb48-8e35-4e04-b682-73cbc20310ee---job-7a3be47a47-input-251f3-SingleBitrate720pEncode-EncodingJob-251f3-r1

Can you please help me on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

it seems that your video has avg_frame_rate of 1000 fps and r_frame_rate of 1000 fps which causes it to fail. We don't support such high fps.
Can you encode the video to a lower frame rate, for example 30 fps, and try again?